# Error registering mscal.ocx for using old calender in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, ocx, regsvr32

I have different pc's with the same configurations (Win7 Prof with Office 2013, exact same build-number). I have a excel file which uses the old calendar control of office 2007.

To solve this problem I register with administrator rights the `mscal.ocx`:

```
regsvr32.exe C:\temp\mscal.ocx
```

It gives me an success message on every pc. But on some pc's I can not use the old calendar control.

[image]

On the pc's that working the calendar control is seen as above in the red square, the pc's it doesn't work the red square is empty and gives the error

> Run Time Error '380' on ListBox [Could not set the Selected property. Invalid property value.]

I searched and compared the registry on the pc's for `mscal.ocx` and they are exactly the same. I also added the reference to the `mscal.ocx` manualy in vba but still the same problem.

Where else can I look to ensure the ocx is correct added? Any idea how to solve it? Thanks

Comment: I think it's common controls you need to get up and running https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2746232

Comment: Works, thanks! You can make an answer if your want and I will accept

Comment: no probs, they can send you mad things like that :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's common controls you need to get up and running support.microsoft.com/en-gb/kb/2746232